# Ubuntu 12.10 - Cannot find -ltcl when I compile my C++ program

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, makefile

I am working on a C++ project and I need to use libtcl.
I am running Ubuntu 12.10 32bits and there is a problem when I try to compile my files :

```
g++ -o executable executable.o -L/usr/share/tcltk -lncurses -ltcl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl
```

libncurses is found but not libtcl...
Do you have any idea?

I have seen that libtcl8.4.so.0 libtcl8.5.so.0 exist in /usr/lib

The makefile that I am using looks like this :

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g
LDFLAGS =
EXEC = executable
LIB = -L/usr/share/tcltk -lncurses -ltcl

all: executable

executable: executable.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXEC) executable.o $(LIB)

executable.o: executable.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c executable.cpp

clean:
    rm -f executable executable.o
```

Thanks

Comment: What about `-ltcl8.4` or `-ltcl8.5`?

Comment: Is there a `libtcl.so` file or link in `/usr/lib` or in `/usr/share/tcltk`?

Comment: I tried with -ltcl8.4 or 8.5 but I have the same error (cannot find -ltcl8.4 or 8.5). And no, there is no file libtcl.so.
There is only libtcl8.4.so.0 and libtcl8.5.so.0 in /usr/lib and folders tcl8  tcl8.4  tcl8.5  tk8.5  tls1.6 with .tcl extension files inside

Comment: @Loric-, just create symlink to the your library like so `#ln -s /usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so.0 /usr/lib/libtcl.so`

Comment: Don't mess with your system directories unless you are ready to take responsibility for what happens in them.

Answer (score 1):

(Answered in a comment. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@soon wrote:

> just create symlink to the your library like so `#ln -s /usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so.0 /usr/lib/libtcl.so`